# How to generate a customized bar chart automatically which taking data from an automated updated csv files inside a Google sheets using Apps Script

Tags: csv, google-apps-script

**This is the example draft graph I try to generate**

[image]

**This is the files in my Google drive**

[image]

for now, I've already successfully automatically generate Google Sheets with data inside is from a CSV file inside my Google Drive. Even though the CSV file is deleted and replaced with a new one, the data inside the generated Google Sheets will be updated and remain only one-sheets instead of creating another one. But now, I wish to carry further which is to automatically generate a customized(take only 2 columns of data from the updated Google Sheets) bar chart and generate it as another tab inside the same Google Sheets. The whole Google Drive should only contain one CSV file, and one Google Sheets with both have the same name.

I do not have much experience in using Apps script, that's why I facing the problem when trying to come out with an automated generated graph. I fail to create a customized graph with a specific requirement. For now, I can't even create a normal graph inside the sheet. Please help.

```
function createGraph() { 
      var data = 
 SpreadsheetApp.openById('17wjzTLFBML_iN4Arnx6vos1JrHAme3ukvGDaoBSCGw'); 
  var sheet = data.getSheets()[0];

  //create chart 
  //if chart created, this will update the existing chart
  if (sheet.getCharts().length > 0){
  var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];
  chart = chart.modify()
  .removeRange(chart.getRanges()[0])
  .addRange(sheet.getRange("Y1:Y501"))
  .addRange(sheet.getRange("V1:V501"))
  .setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', true)
  .setOption('treatLabelsAsText', true)
  .setOption('applyAggregateData',0)
  .setNumHeaders(1)
  .setPosition(5, 6, 5, 5)
  .setOption("title", "Chart")
  .build()
  sheet.updateChart(chart)

}
else{

 //create new chart
var chart = sheet.newChart()
.setChartType(Charts.ChartType.COLUMN)
//.addRange(sheet.getRange("Y1:Y501"))
.addRange(sheet.getRange("V1:V501"))
.setMergeStrategy(Charts.ChartMergeStrategy.MERGE_ROWS)
.setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', true)
.setOption('applyAggregateData',0)
.setOption('treatLabelsAsText', true)
.setNumHeaders(1)
.setPosition(5, 6, 5, 5)
.setOption("title", "Chart")
.build()
sheet.insertChart(chart)

}
```

}

From the data inside the Google Sheets, I wish to only take the 'Condition' column and 'Case Type 3'column and 'Owner column'. Where the graph x-axis is condition and separate by owner and case type 3. While the graph y-axis is the quantity.

Comment: Can you please provide some information about how you created the chart in your snippet?

Comment: I'm using another software which called Tableau to visualize the data, for Tableau, I just drag the data inside and it will generate various chart pattern, but for now , I'm wanna to use the Apps script to generate the chart based on the updated data inside the Google Sheet, could you help please?

Answer (score 0):

### To your first concern about not being able to create a normal graph:

The error lies in your range definition, the correct method syntax is: 
[getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows-numcolumns), so in your case:

```
var range = sheet.getRange(startRow, startColumn,  sheet.getLastRow()-startRow+1, numOfColumns);
```

I see that you just edited your question, but actually the code before the edit was correct apart from this line.

### As for creating a graph similar to what you did with Tableau:

Unfortunately, you cannot do the same with simple chart building in Apps Script. You will need to use [google visualization](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start), which you cannot use directly in Apps Script, but have to embed it in the  part of an html file bound to your Apps Script. You will need to use the [group()](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google_visualization_data_group) function, similar to his case:

[Google Charts Data Grouping for column chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47004716/google-charts-data-grouping-for-column-chart)

### An easy workaround:

The closest thing you can do with simple Apps Script chart building based on your code is creating two graphs and positioning them next to each other:

[image]

However, you would need to restructure your data. For the grouping feature, each Graph must have "Owner" is the x-axis and 3 y series (for each condition) - the way you can see it in the snippet above. All you need to adjust in your code (the one before edit) is the range size, to make sure all your data columns for one chart are included.
Also, if you want the columns to be vertical, as in your snippet, and not horizontal - you are talking about a column chart and not a bar chart. Based on your code, here a possible solution:

```
 function createGraph() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet() // You can replace this with gettingSheetbyName()
       // Read variables
       var startRow1 = 13;  // What row to start reading at
       var startColumn1 = 8;  // What column to start reading
       var startRow2 = 13;  // What row to start reading at
       var startColumn2 = 13;  // What column to start reading  
       var numOfColumns = 4;  // Number of columns to read   
     // Graph variables
        var posX1 = 6;  // Column to anchor graph to
        var posX2 = 12;  // Column to anchor graph to
        var posY = 16;  // Row to anchor graph to
        var width = 600; // Graph Width
        var xTitle = 'Condition'; // XAxis Title
        var yTitle = 'Number of Records'; // YAxis Title
        var chartType = Charts.ChartType.COLUMN; // Chart Type
        var range1 = sheet.getRange(startRow1, startColumn1,  sheet.getLastRow()-startRow1+1, numOfColumns);
        var range2 = sheet.getRange(startRow2, startColumn2,  sheet.getLastRow()-startRow2+1, numOfColumns);

        var chart1 = sheet.getCharts()[0];
        var chart2 = sheet.getCharts()[0];

 //If charts already exist, update them
   if (chart1){
     chart1.modify()
     .removeRange(chart1.getRanges()[0])
     .addRange(range1)
     .setPosition(posY, posX1, 0, 0)
     .setOption('width', width)
     .setOption('vAxis.title', yTitle)
     .setOption('hAxis.title', xTitle)
     .setChartType(chartType)
     .build();
     sheet.updateChart(chart1);
   }
    //If not, create them
   else {
     var chart1 = sheet.newChart();
     chart1.addRange(range1)
     .setPosition(posY, posX1, 0, 0)
     .setOption('title', 'Out of Box Failure')
     .setOption('width', width)
     .setOption('vAxis.title', yTitle)
     .setOption('hAxis.title', xTitle)
     .setChartType(chartType);
     sheet.insertChart(chart1.build());
   }
    //If charts already exist, update them
   if (chart2){
     chart2.modify()
     .removeRange(chart2.getRanges()[0])
     .addRange(range2)
     .setPosition(posY, posX2, 0, 0)
     .setOption('width', width)
     .setOption('vAxis.title', yTitle)
     .setOption('hAxis.title', xTitle)
     .setChartType(chartType)
     .build();
     sheet.updateChart(chart2);
   }
    //If not, create them
   else {
     var chart2 = sheet.newChart();
     chart2.addRange(range2)
     .setPosition(posY, posX2, 0, 0)
     .setOption('title', 'Deliver quality')
     .setOption('width', width)
     .setOption('vAxis.title', yTitle)
     .setOption('hAxis.title', xTitle)
     .setChartType(chartType);
     sheet.insertChart(chart2.build());
   }

 }
```

If this is not sufficient for you, you will need to have a deeper look at the implementation of Google Visualization. The quickstart linked above should give you a good idea about how to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But my data in the google sheets is quite huge and the columns that I want is separate with each other. For instance, "Owner" data is in column Y , "Case Type 3" is in column V and "Condition" is in column L. I got confused on how to choose the data range from the Apps Script. Much appreciated for your help as I'm just new to this Apps Script.

Comment: And fyi, I didn't mention another requirement inside my questions which is Out of Box failure and Delivered Quality is all within a column which is called ' Case 3  Type'. Especially the 'Delivered Quality', it is a grouped data of the rest except for 'Out of Box failure' inside the ' Case 3 Type' column, So , ya, I have many filter to be done and there's where I stuck

Comment: @ Wei Sen Ng: Can you please provide me a sample sheet with your data to get a better understanding?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZrMtrC6bPB7lbIjDSZkCvKvRYYhbVfCkFY5AKKTqbUc/edit#gid=0

Comment: hi and I just uploaded a sample sheet for better understanding, please do focus to those column that I mentioned previously : "Owner", "Condition", and "Case Type 3". The required chart pattern is at Sheet 2 inside the link. Much appreciated! I hope u can help, I'm clueless .

Comment: What you want achieve, can unfortunately not be done with simple chart building in Apps Script. You will need to use google visualization, which you cannot use directly in Apps Script, but have to embed it in the <script> part of an html file bound to your Apps Script. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @ziganotschka How to call data from google sheets in google visualisation? Its very difficult to find a tutorial for that

Comment: You can access data from the sheet with the getRange(...) and getValues() methods, and then, when you define you Google Visualization DataTable, add the values retrieved from the sheet with addRow() or addColumn(). Here more information about defining data tables: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable